# What is the best way to display currency amounts (smallest units from any currency) from Stripe?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, currency

According to [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal):

> All API requests expect amounts to be provided in a currency’s smallest unit. For example, to charge 10 USD, provide an amount value of 1000 (i.e., 1000 cents).

This seems to be easy to display in the browser for USD where I can do

```js
const currencyFromStripe = "usd"
const amountFromStripe = 1000

const dollarAmount = amountFromStripe / 100

const userFriendlyAmount = new Intl.NumberFormat(navigator.language || "en-US", {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currencyFromStripe
}).format(amountFromStripe)

console.log(userFriendlyAmount)
```

that returns

```js
"$10.00"
```

But this doesn't work for currencies that don't divide by `100` (such as the Japanese Yen) to get the given currency that Stripe returns.

How do I convert the amount, which is any given currency's smallest unit (combined with the currency string), to a user-friendly display like how the `Intl` API does? Is there a library that does this?

Comment: and actually, the European model of electronic invoices has price up to 4 decimal digits, and the Italian model has 8 decimal digits for price amount... pricing in payment services should have a big review ... as an example ... cryptocurrencies. - **Regarding your question**, check the documentation under [currencies > zero-decimal](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal)

Comment: I was actually looking at that page and I had completely missed some critical details. It looks like I'll have to manually make an exclusion list to omit that `/ 100` for those specified currencies. Thanks!

Comment: Please could you let me know the solution to this issue. I'm facing this issue right now.